# Creating a UK Heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, heatmap, choropleth

I have a data frame for UK data that looks something like this:

```
longitude   latitude     region           priority
51.307733   -0.75708898  South East       High
51.527477   -0.20646542  London           Medium
51.725135   0.4747223    East of England  Low
```

This dataframe is several thousand rows long. I want a heatmap of the UK broken down by the regions and colour intensity to be dependent on the priority in each region.

I would like to know the best way to turn this into a heatmap of the UK. I have tried geoPandas and Plotly but I have no functioning knowledge of these. Are these the best way to do it or is there a tool out there that you can simply upload your data to and it will plot it for you? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of job i use to go with folium, which is great to work with maps, 
But for the heatMap you have to have your "priority" column as float!

```
import folium
from folium import plugins
from folium.plugins import HeatMap


my_map = folium.Map(location=[51.5074, 0.1278],
                    zoom_start = 13) # for UK 


your_dataframe['latitude'] = your_dataframe['latitude'].astype(float)
your_dataframe['longitude'] = your_dataframe['longitude'].astype(float)
your_dataframe['priority'] = your_dataframe['priority'].astype(float)


heat_df = your_dataframe[['latitude', 'longitude','priority']]
heat_df = heat_df.dropna(axis=0, subset=['latitude','longitude','priority'])

# List comprehension to make out list of lists
heat_data = [[row['latitude'],row['longitude'],row['priority']] for index, row in heat_df.iterrows()]

my_map.add_children(plugins.HeatMap(heat_data))
my_map.save('map.html')
```

and then you have to open map.html with yout browser